# Connecting to Jabber Server Via Proxy in Python (XMPPY)

Tags: python, proxy, xmpp, xmpppy

Trying to connect to jabber with proxy:

```
 > JCON = xmpp.Client(server=SERVER, port=PORT, debug=[])
 > con=JCON.connect(server=(CONNECT_SERVER, PORT), proxy=(127.0.0.1, 80), secure=0,use_srv=True)
```

Without proxy it connects fine. Is the proxy syntax right?
Referring to 'Client.py' in XMPPY  (https://github.com/normanr/xmpppy/blob/master/xmpp/client.py) might help to understand the syntax.

Hoping for a response soon!

Answer (score 1):

From the code you linked:

'proxy' argument is a dictionary with mandatory keys 'host' and 'port' (proxy address)

Comment: What is the snippet that should be added?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it into a dictionary, like this.

```
   con=JCON.connect(server=(CONNECT_SERVER, PORT), proxy={'host':'127.0.0.1', 'port':'80'}, secure=0,use_srv=True)
```

If you need authentication, you add 'user':'me','password':'secret' to the dictionary, like this

```
   con=JCON.connect(server=(CONNECT_SERVER, PORT), proxy={'host':'127.0.0.1', 'port':'80','user':'me','password':'secret'}, secure=0,use_srv=True)
```